# Pair-wise difference using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, segmentation-fault

I was asked to translate this pseudo code into a C program:

```
rep := 0
while A not empty:
    B := []
    for x in A, y in A:
        if x != y: append absolute_value(x - y) to B
    A := B
    rep := rep + 1
```

and I end up with this:

```
int iterateIt(int a_count, int* a) {
    unsigned long long i, j, k;
    unsigned long long count = a_count;

    for( i = 1 ; i < a_count ; i++ )
        count *= count-1;

    int *b = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    count = 0;
    k = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < a_count ; i++ ){
        for( j = i ; j < a_count ; j++ ){
            if(a[i] != a[j]){
                b[k] = abs(a[i] - a[j]);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    if( k > 0){
        return 1 + iterateIt(k, b);
    }
    free(b);
    return 1;
}
```

I used recursion to return the number of iteration of the algorithm. Practically I take the difference between any two different objects of A and put the absolute value in B, on which I recur.
For simple input I get the correct result but I don't understand why for input like: 
`16` `1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512 1024 2048 4096 8192 16384 32768`
or `4` `1 352 9483 50000`
(the first number is the number of element of A)

I get a segmentation fault error.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you put `count *= count-1;` in a loop? What does it compute?

Comment: You do not test the return value of `malloc()`.  My guess would be that you are computing a huge or even negative (because overflow) value in `count`, `malloc()` is therefore failing, and you are then attempting to write through the resulting null pointer.

Comment: Do you use an IDE? Does it have a debugger? Do you know how to use it? It is your best friend and will easilly let you resolve problems like this without having to ask us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `count` is wrong. Your second iteration is already humongous.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t total_allocated = 0;

int iterateIt(int a_count, int* a) {
    unsigned long long i, j, k;
    unsigned long long count = a_count;

    for( i = 1 ; i < a_count ; i++ )
        count *= count-1;

    size_t size = count * sizeof(int);
    printf("Allocating %llu ints: %llu bytes\n", count, (unsigned long long)size);
    total_allocated += size;
    printf("Total allocated: %llu bytes\n", (unsigned long long)total_allocated);
    int *b = (int *) malloc(count * sizeof(int));
    count = 0;
    k = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < a_count ; i++ ){
        for( j = i ; j < a_count ; j++ ){
            if(a[i] != a[j]){
                b[k] = abs(a[i] - a[j]);
                k++;
            }
        }
    }

    if( k > 0){
        return 1 + iterateIt(k, b);
    }
    free(b);
    return 1;
}

int main (void)
{
    iterateIt(4, (int[4]){1,352,9483,50000});
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Allocating 17292 ints: 69168 bytes
Total allocated: 69168 bytes
Allocating 12550317587327992670 ints: 13307782201892867448 bytes
Total allocated: 13307782201892936616 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

First consider this line:

```
return 1 + iterateIt(k, b);
```

The `b` array never gets freed on this `return` but if `k` is zero, it does.  Let's rewrite this code to clean it up a bit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned iterateIt(size_t a_count, int *a) {

    unsigned rep = 1;

    int *b = calloc(a_count * a_count, sizeof(int));

    size_t k = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < a_count; i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < a_count; j++) {
            if (a[i] != a[j]) {
                b[k++] = abs(a[i] - a[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (k > 0) {
        rep += iterateIt(k, b);
    }

    free(b);

    return rep;
}

int main() {

    int x[] = {1, 324, 54};

    printf("%u\n", iterateIt(sizeof(x) / sizeof(int), x));

    return 0;
}
```

Watching the value of `a_count`, the program tries to allocate too much memory and fails.

**UPDATE**

Since the two halves of the matrix end up identical, I fixed the above code to do what the OP did, just process 1/2 the matrix, i.e. `j` starts at `i + 1` since the two halves end up identical.  I also ignore the diagonal as it's always zeros.  Then the code completes for the three numbers in my example code but blows up again when I increase the array to four values.

I believe the recursive nature of the OP's solution is elegant and a non-issue but just to confirm, here's an iterative solution that fails to perform and not due to lack of stack memory:

```
unsigned iterateIt(size_t a_count, int *a) {

    unsigned rep = 1;

    bool first_time = true;

    while (true) {

        int *b = calloc((a_count * a_count) / 2, sizeof(int));

        if (b == NULL) {
            perror("calloc failed!");
            exit(1);
        }

        size_t b_count = 0;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < a_count; i++) {
            for (size_t j = i + 1; j < a_count; j++) {
                if (a[i] != a[j]) {
                    b[b_count ++] = abs(a[i] - a[j]);
                }
            }
        }

        if (b_count == 0) {
            free(b);
            break;
        }

        if (first_time) {
            first_time = false;
        } else {
            free(a);
        }

        a = b;
        a_count = b_count;

        rep++;
    }

    return rep;
}
```

Comment: The convergence is definitely there: at each round the maximal value decreases. I don't see a reason for a recursive approach though.